# Determine whether user is logged in

Tags: c#, .net, authentication

What's the best/most efficient way whether the user of my .NET web application is currently logged in.

I'm currently using `Membership.GetUser() != null`, but now that I realize that this involves a DB-roundtrip, I wonder if there's a better way. Maybe `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have answered your own question. The `IsAuthenticated` property is the best way to do this.